# How to isolate shortcuts to the currently focused display in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 OS (kernel 6.5.0-21-generic) with GNOME 42.9 and two monitors. When I execute a system-level shortcut like `Super`, I get `Activities` displayed on both displays which is not useful and also distracting. At the same time, some other shortcuts like `Ctrl-Alt-T` work on the currently active display which is what I want.

I haven't found a suitable option either in `gnome-tweaks`, or in `dconf`. I'm wondering how to make all shortcuts to be display-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The GNOME extension [Multiple Monitor Panels](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/323/multiple-monitor-panels/) appears to perform that function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried to install it, but never discovered what it does due to an error during the installation which possibly has something to do with incompatibility with GNOME 42.9

Comment: seems from the shell version drop down that it only goes as far as 3.7.2 but sometime newer shell versions will work. I guess you could always consider [contacting the author](https://github.com/darkxst) to see if there are plans to cover newer versions of the shell.